# Deadbolt play framework 2.8 and dynamic constraint

Tags: java, playframework, guice

I'm trying to use deadolt in my java play framework 2.8 projects to only allow some actions in the controller to be called if the request contains an api_key. Reading the guide the best solution is to use Dynamic constraint support. But once the DynamicResourceHandler interface is implemented I always get 4 errors.

In my **build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.8.1"
)
```

In my **application.conf**

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule
    enabled += modules.CustomDeadboltModule
  }
}
```

In my modules a class **CustomDeadboltModule**

```
public class CustomDeadboltModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    public void configure(){
        bind(DynamicResourceHandler.class).to(CustomDynamicResourceHandler.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

In a package security.deadbolt my class CustomDynamicResourceHandler that implements DynamicResourceHandler interface:

```
@Singleton
public class CustomDynamicResourceHandler implements DynamicResourceHandler {

    @Inject
    private  com.typesafe.config.Config configuration;

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Boolean> isAllowed(String name, Optional<String> meta, DeadboltHandler deadboltHandler, Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> result = new CompletableFuture<>();

        // check if my credential matching current value result= true for instance 

        return result;
    }





    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Boolean> checkPermission(String permissionValue, Optional<String> meta, DeadboltHandler deadboltHandler, Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So in the end I add the @Dynamic to actions in my test controller:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Dynamic("")
    public Result index() {
        return ok("ok");
    }
```

}

So when I try to perform a request I receive this error:

```
> 1) No implementation for
> be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.BeforeAuthCheckCache was bound.  
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.BeforeAuthCheckCache
>     for the 2nd parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction.<init>(DynamicAction.java:46)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction
> 
> 2) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.HandlerCache
> was bound.   while locating
> be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.HandlerCache
>     for the 1st parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction.<init>(DynamicAction.java:46)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction
> 
> 3) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.PatternCache
> was bound.   while locating
> be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.PatternCache
>     for the 3rd parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic.<init>(ConstraintLogic.java:53)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic
>     for the 4th parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction.<init>(DynamicAction.java:46)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction
> 
> 4) No implementation for be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.SubjectCache
> was bound.   while locating
> be.objectify.deadbolt.java.cache.SubjectCache
>     for the 2nd parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic.<init>(ConstraintLogic.java:53)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic
>     for the 4th parameter of be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction.<init>(DynamicAction.java:46)
> while locating be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.DynamicAction
```